# Sort by: Change ordering of one field in multi-field sort

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sorting

When using ruby's `sort_by!` to do a multi field sort, how can you change to ordering of just one of the fields its sorting by

ex:

`a = [{:id => 1, :email_type=>"discover", :date=>2016-10-25 12:27:21 -0400},     {:id => 2, :email_type=>"personal", :date=>2016-10-25 12:27:34 -0400},           {:id => 3, :email_type=>"discover", :date=>2016-10-25 12:27:42 -0400}]`

`a.sort_by! {|e| [e[:email_type], e[:date]]}`

returns

`[{:id => 1, :email_type=>"discover", :date=>2016-10-25 12:27:21 -0400},                   {:id => 3, :email_type=>"discover", :date=>2016-10-25 12:27:42 -0400},              {:id => 2, :email_type=>"personal", :date=>2016-10-25 12:27:34 -0400}]`

sorted by type, then date ASC. However I want date DESC

`[{:id => 3, :email_type=>"discover", :date=>2016-10-25 12:27:42 -0400},             {:id => 1, :email_type=>"discover", :date=>2016-10-25 12:27:21 -0400},                              {:id => 2, :email_type=>"personal", :date=>2016-10-25 12:27:34 -0400}]`

how would I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
arr = [{:id => 1, :email_type=>"discover", :date=>"2016-10-25 12:27:21 -0400"},
       {:id => 2, :email_type=>"personal", :date=>"2016-10-25 12:27:34 -0400"},
       {:id => 3, :email_type=>"discover", :date=>"2016-10-25 12:27:42 -0400"}]
```

Here are two ways of doing that.

**Convert date-times to `DateTime` objects, convert to seconds and sort on `:email_type` and negative of seconds**

```
require 'date'

arr.sort_by do |h| 
  [h[:email_type], -DateTime.strptime(h[:date], '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S %z').to_time.to_i]
end    
  #=> [{:id=>3, :email_type=>"discover", :date=>"2016-10-25 12:27:42 -0400"},
  #    {:id=>1, :email_type=>"discover", :date=>"2016-10-25 12:27:21 -0400"},
  #    {:id=>2, :email_type=>"personal", :date=>"2016-10-25 12:27:34 -0400"}]
```

**Construct and array of `:email_type` values in the desired final order, sort by the index of that array and the date-time string, then reverse**

```
email_type_order = arr.map { |h| h[:email_type] }.uniq.sort.reverse
  #=> ["personal", "discover"]
arr.sort_by { |h| [email_type_order.index(h[:email_type]), h[:date]] }.reverse
  #=> [{:id=>3, :email_type=>"discover", :date=>"2016-10-25 12:27:42 -0400"},
  #    {:id=>1, :email_type=>"discover", :date=>"2016-10-25 12:27:21 -0400"},
  #    {:id=>2, :email_type=>"personal", :date=>"2016-10-25 12:27:34 -0400"}]
```

For Ruby v2.2+ you can avoid the final `reverse` operation by using [Enumerable#max_by](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-max_by) with an argument equal to the size of the array:

```
email_type_order = arr.map { |h| h[:email_type] }.uniq.sort.reverse
  #=> ["personal", "discover"]
arr.max_by(arr.size) { |h| [email_type_order.index(h[:email_type]), h[:date]] }
```

Note that here we can sort on the date-time string (i.e, without converting it to a `DateTime` object) because the strings are ordered by year, month, day, hour, minute, second and time zone, and fields are left-padded with zeroes.